# Red wine out of white cotton shirt

Tags: cleaning, clothing

Some red wine (red mascotta) was splashed onto a nice new white shirt that has been worn maybe 5 times.

This happened about 3 hours ago and I just noticed it now. The material is cotton.

What should I used and what process should I follow to help get this out? Soak, don't soak, dish soap, oxy clean, scrub, or what?

Answer (score 4):

White wine

It's likely dry by now, so I would think use a little white wine to wet it. Try dabbing it out to start. Then soak it in white wine and, if necessary, wash it with cool to cold water. (Hot water is bad).

I've heard this many times before, and it sounds funny, but it makes sense if you think about it. This website also suggests it. (And so do many more on google)

https://www.cleanipedia.com/gb/laundry/how-to-remove-red-wine-stains-from-clothes

Just no whining if it doesn't work ;D

Comment: Yes, that's the one I do, with a slight modification. Drench in white wine, soak up with a towel, repeat as required, then extract the rest with salt. The last step may apply mainly to carpets where washing is not that easy.

Comment: Right, my mom uses salt all the time like that too! (I wouldn't suggest drenching first here to prevent possible spreading of the wine, but definitely on carpets!)

Answer (score 3):

All the purists will shudder, however I've had good fortune dipping and soaking stained clothing in a diluted solution of clorox, and letting it soak for a few hours - no rubbing just soaking.  Of course then once removed, put it through the washer.

Comment: White cotton is the perfect candidate for bleaching. Unlike a colour or pattern, you don't need to worry that the bleach will lose you the desired colour. And unlike a synthetic, you don't need to worry it might yellow. I used to buy white cotton for my small children for that reason - it is the most bleach-friendly fabric there is